# Very Strange Error with Camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I added code to pick Camera using `CameraInfo` because just adding `Camera.open()` was not working on `HTC devices` and I changed the `holder` in `mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder)` to `mHolder` which is an instance variable.

I try to open the custom Camera in the `onResume` of an Activity,in the logcat output I have noticed that the code goes into `surfaceChanged` after `surfaceCreated` because that is where I set the Camera Preview size using `Parameters`,then it seems to have failed to allocate memory: `GenericAlloc: Failed to allocate device memory`(I have low memory on my device **~2.47GB** free space)mis it because of that.

I get the following huge,unknown error,you can take a look at my [CameraActivity](http://pastebin.com/vDrLKasd) and my [CameraPreview](http://pastebin.com/XL0uATXE):

```
    CameraClient(127): Opening camera 0
    CameraHAL(127): camera_device open
    CameraHAL(127): Adapter state switch PREVIEW_ACTIVE Invalid Op! event = 0xf
    CameraPreview(4660): Camera Preview size set to 1920X1080
    IMGSRV(127): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: Cannot unregister a locked buffer (ID=2100)
   GraphicBufferMapper(127): unregisterBuffer(0x400a7470) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
   IMGSRV(127): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: Cannot unregister a locked buffer (ID=2102)
   GraphicBufferMapper(127): unregisterBuffer(0x458372f8) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
   IMGSRV(127): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: Cannot unregister a locked buffer (ID=2104)
   GraphicBufferMapper(127): unregisterBuffer(0x40d5ffd8) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
   IMGSRV(127): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: Cannot unregister a locked buffer (ID=2106)
   GraphicBufferMapper(127): unregisterBuffer(0x40d5fa90) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
   CameraHAL(127): Adapter state switch PREVIEW_ACTIVE Invalid Op! event = 0xf
   Surface(127): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x400a7470
   CameraHAL(127): cancel_buffer() failed: Invalid argument (22)
   IMGSRV(127): :0: gralloc_module_unlock: Buffer is already unlocked
   GraphicBufferMapper(127): unlock(...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
   Surface(127): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x400a7470
   CameraHAL(127): cancel_buffer() failed: Invalid argument (22)
   dalvikvm(4660): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 183K, 3% free 9939K/10160K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
   CameraPreview(4660): Camera Preview size set to 1920X1080
   IMGSRV(124): :0: PVRSRVAllocDeviceMem: Error 1 returned
   IMGSRV(124): :0: GenericAlloc: Failed to allocate device memory
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): alloc(1952, 1128, 256, 00000b02, ...) failed -12 (Out of memory)
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): Allocated buffers:
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): 0x40027f90:  276.00 KiB |  720 ( 736) x   96 |        5 | 0x00000b00
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): 0x4002f5e0: unknown     | 1952 (4096) x 1128 |      100 | 0x00000b02
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): 0x40e30f18:  143.75 KiB |  720 ( 736) x   50 |        5 | 0x00000b00
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): 0x40eb8580: unknown     | 1952 (4096) x 1128 |      100 | 0x00000b02
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): 0x40ebc7f0: 3680.00 KiB |  720 ( 736) x 1280 |        1 | 0x00000933
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): 0x40ebdeb8: unknown     | 1952 (4096) x 1128 |      100 | 0x00000b02
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): 0x40ebf0f0: 3404.00 KiB |  720 ( 736) x 1184 |        5 | 0x00000b00
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): 0x40ec3cb8: unknown     | 1952 (4096) x 1128 |      100 | 0x00000b02
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): 0x40f1ca58: 3404.00 KiB |  720 ( 736) x 1184 |        5 | 0x00000b00
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): 0x40f1dd60: 3404.00 KiB |  720 ( 736) x 1184 |        5 | 0x00000b00
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): 0x40f807e8: 3404.00 KiB |  720 ( 736) x 1184 |        5 | 0x00000b00
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): 0x412e9048: 5120.00 KiB |  720 (1024) x 1280 |        5 | 0x00001a00
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): 0x412e90d8: 5120.00 KiB |  720 (1024) x 1280 |        5 | 0x00001a00
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): 0x41327178:  143.75 KiB |  720 ( 736) x   50 |        5 | 0x00000b00
   GraphicBufferAllocator(124): 0x41329d28: 3680.00 KiB |  720 ( 736) 
   (124): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=1952, h=1128) failed (Out of memory), handle=0x0
   BufferQueue(124): [SurfaceView] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceComposer::createGraphicBuffer failed
   CameraHAL(127): dequeueBuffer failed: Out of memory (12)
   IMGSRV(127): :0: gralloc_module_unlock: Buffer is already unlocked
   GraphicBufferMapper(127): unlock(...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
   BufferQueue(124): [SurfaceView] cancelBuffer: slot 3 is not owned by the client (state=0)
   IMGSRV(127): :0: gralloc_module_unlock: Buffer is already unlocked
   GraphicBufferMapper(127): unlock(...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
   BufferQueue(124): [SurfaceView] cancelBuffer: slot 1 is not owned by the client (state=0)
   CameraHAL(127): Error occurred, performing cleanup
   CameraHAL(127): AppCallbackNotifier received error -12
   CameraHAL(127): AppCallbackNotifier mNotifyCb -12
   dalvikvm(586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 616K, 8% free 10610K/11532K, paused 6ms+7ms, total 45ms
    dalvikvm(586): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
    dalvikvm(586): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 20ms
    EsService(9002): readResults: read results: 2, lastRequestId: 12
    dalvikvm(5174): GC_CONCURRENT freed 561K, 21% free 9210K/11564K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 24ms
    ActivityManager(379): Process com.android.launcher (pid 8391) has died.
    dalvikvm(9002): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2856K, 10% free 27486K/30376K, paused 3ms+8ms, total 49ms
    libEGL(9002): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
    libEGL(9002): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
    libEGL(9002): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
    ActivityManager(379): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
    ActivityManager(379): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{429176f8 u0   com.blutechnologies.scancard/.CameraActivity}
   dalvikvm(586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 612K, 9% free 10604K/11532K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 39ms
    dalvikvm(586): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 19ms
    dalvikvm(586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 604K, 9% free 10502K/11532K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 48ms
    WindowManager(379): Screenshot Window{421c84f0 u0   
    com.blutechnologies.scancard/com.blutechnologies.scancard.CameraActivity} was all  
    black! mSurfaceLayer=21050 minLayer=21015 maxLayer=21050
    dalvikvm(487): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2272K, 25% free 23405K/31048K, paused 37ms, total 37ms

    ActivityManager(379): START u0 
    {act=com.android.systemui.recent.action.TOGGLE_RECENTS flg=0x10800000 
    cmp=com.android.systemui/.recent.RecentsActivity (has extras)} from pid 487
    dalvikvm(379): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3773K, 25% free 27472K/36180K, paused 92ms, total 92ms
    dalvikvm(487): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 781K, 21% free 24624K/31048K, paused 23ms, total 23ms

    ActivityManager(379): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{429176f8 u0 
    com.blutechnologies.scancard/.CameraActivity}
    ActivityManager(379): Process com.google.android.apps.magazines (pid 8851) has died.
    ActivityManager(379): Activity stop timeout for ActivityRecord{4290f880 u0 
    com.blutechnologies.scancard/.MainActivity}
    ActivityManager(379): Activity stop timeout for ActivityRecord{429176f8 u0 
    com.blutechnologies.scancard/.CameraActivity}
    ActivityManager(379): Activity reported stop, but no longer stopping: 
    ActivityRecord{429176f8 u0 com.blutechnologies.scancard/.CameraActivity}
    InputDispatcher(379): Application is not responding: Window{421c84f0 u0 
    com.blutechnologies.scancard/com.blutechnologies.scancard.CameraActivity}.  It has 
    been 5019.4ms since event, 5003.4ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting because 
    the touched window has not finished processing the input events that were 
    previously delivered to it.
    WindowManager(379): Input event dispatching timed out sending to 
    com.blutechnologies.scancard/com.blutechnologies.scancard.CameraActivity
    Process(379): Sending signal. PID: 4660 SIG: 3
    dalvikvm(4660): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    dalvikvm(4660): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    Process(379): Sending signal. PID: 379 SIG: 3
    dalvikvm(379): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    dalvikvm(379): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    Process(379): Sending signal. PID: 487 SIG: 3
    dalvikvm(487): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    Process(379): Sending signal. PID: 606 SIG: 3
    dalvikvm(606): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    dalvikvm(606): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    Process(379): Sending signal. PID: 613 SIG: 3
    dalvikvm(613): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    dalvikvm(613): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    dalvikvm(487): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    dalvikvm(379): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3869K, 24% free 27763K/36180K, paused 3ms+9ms,  
    total 103ms
    Process(379): Sending signal. PID: 3927 SIG: 3
    dalvikvm(3927): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    dalvikvm(3927): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    ActivityManager(379): ANR in com.blutechnologies.scancard   
    (com.blutechnologies.scancard/.CameraActivity)
    ActivityManager(379): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
    ActivityManager(379): Load: 1.56 / 1.66 / 1.5
    ActivityManager(379): CPU usage from 6021ms to 0ms ago:
    ActivityManager(379):   11% 379/system_server: 7.5% user + 3.5% kernel / faults:  
    910 minor 6 major
    ActivityManager(379):   7.1% 124/surfaceflinger: 5.6% user + 1.4% kernel / faults: 
    101 minor
    ActivityManager(379):   1.1% 8983/kworker/u:5: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):   1% 5754/kworker/u:2: 0% user + 1% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):   0.6% 127/mediaserver: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):   0.6% 7324/kworker/u:4: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):   0.5% 487/com.android.systemui: 0.3% user + 0.1% kernel / 
    faults: 1 minor
    ActivityManager(379):   0.5% 9030/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):   0.3% 117/vold: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):   0.3% 3927/com.whatsapp: 0.3% user + 0% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):   0.1% 82/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):   0.1% 95/ueventd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):   0% 108/irq/206-mms_ts: 0% user + 0% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):   0.1% 121/netd: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):   0% 443/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):   0.1% 586/com.google.process.location: 0.1% user + 0% kernel 
    / faults: 1 minor
    ActivityManager(379):   0.1% 7385/com.example.newcontactlayout: 0.1% user + 0% 
    kernel / faults: 1 minor
    ActivityManager(379): 12% TOTAL: 6.8% user + 5% kernel + 0.1% iowait
    ActivityManager(379): CPU usage from 1386ms to 1904ms later with 99% awake:
    ActivityManager(379):   5.6% 379/system_server: 3.7% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 
    11 minor
    ActivityManager(379):     5.6% 395/ActivityManager: 1.8% user + 3.7% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):     1.8% 385/Compiler: 1.8% user + 0% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):     1.8% 391/SensorService: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):     1.8% 406/UEventObserver: 1.8% user + 0% kernel
    ActivityManager(379):   1.3% 3927/com.whatsapp: 0% user + 1.3% kernel
    ActivityManager(379): 3.8% TOTAL: 1.9% user + 1.9% kernel
    ActivityManager(379): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
    ActivityManager(379): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{429176f8 u0     
    com.blutechnologies.scancard/.CameraActivity}
```

This is my XML for landscape:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

 <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             />

    <com.blutechnologies.scancard.ShutterButton android:id="@+id/btn_capture"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:src="@drawable/btn_capture"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                 />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my XML for portrait:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
    >
 <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             />

    <com.blutechnologies.scancard.ShutterButton android:id="@+id/btn_capture"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:src="@drawable/btn_capture"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             
                 />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Now it looks like nothing can connect to the Camera,not even the default Camera app.Why did the error occur and how can I resolve it?

## EDIT:

This seems to be a freak occurance,I switched the phone off and turned it back on again and it seems to be working just fine.Another cause could be calling this code in `surfaceDestroyed`:

```
  private void killCamera()
{
    if(mCamera!=null)
    {
        mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera=null;
    }
}
```